# Pharo: How to increase MouseMoveEvent Frequency?

Tags: events, mouse, frequency, smalltalk, pharo

In the [Pharo book](http://pharo.gemtalksystems.com/book/LanguageAndLibraries/GUI/TypicalPolymorphApplication/PaintCanvas/?_s=b-vzidH-g71iZgcC&_k=avzlKMzGtCV4COM5&_n&8) there is an example for a Paint Canvas.

The problem is that the frequency in which mouse move events are passed to the handler is rather low, therefore you cannot draw continous paths if you move the mouse too quickly. 
Is there some way to increase the update frequency for a morph? In Squeak, there is a SketchMorphEditor which does not have that problem, but I have not figured out why yet. 
I am using Pharo 5.0.

Comment: Have you tried `#captureEventsUntil:`? It cycles the world as soon as the block argument completes its evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried it now, but unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: An alternative would be to interpolate between the points, since I'd like to perform gesture recognition and I am not interested in the exact drawing path. Though it would be nice to know how to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Have you tried increasing FPS from 50 (default) to e.g. 120? `WorldState MinCycleLapse: (1000/120.0).`

Comment: I noticed a slight improvement, but the problem remains (also with higher values such as 500 fps). In the meanwhile, I'll dissect the SketchEditorMorph from Squeak. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It looks like that the SketchEditorMorph does interpolation as well (with Pen>>#goto:). Although there are some tricks to improve responsiveness, it is probably best to draw a line between the last point and the current one. With that method hand-drawings look fine.

Comment: If you found a solution, then add your own answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to increase the sampling rate. Even if it could be done, it would be a very bad idea for several reasons.
First, linear interpolation yields fairly good results (which can be improved with techniques like anti-aliasing, if necessary):

[image]

Second, we cannot rely on the sampling rate to be the same on every machine and to have consistent results. And third, since I plan to use a gesture recognizer, algorithms like the [$1 Recognizer](http://faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/uist-07.01.pdf) do not rely on sampling rates and work surprisingly well.